# C++: partial function specialization for void not allowed - alternative solution?

Tags: c++, function, templates, partial-specialization

I think I understand by now why partial function templates are considered confusing and unnecessary, and are thus not allowed by the C++ standard.  I would however appreciate some help with re-phrasing the following function w/o partial specialization.  FWIW, the function is a member of a non-specialized class:

```
template <typename IMPL, typename RET>
RET call (functor <IMPL> func, 
          IMPL * impl)
{ 
  return func.call (impl);
}

template <typename IMPL>
void call <IMPL, void_t> (functor <IMPL> func, 
                          IMPL * impl) 
{ 
  func.call (impl);
}
```

The problem here is that I can't overload on the function's return type. Also, the typename I want to specialize on is not used as function parameter - another reason why overloading does not help.  Yes, I could introduce a dummy parameter, to force overloading, but that is ugly, isn't it?

Finally, why the heck isn't 'void' a type in C++?  That would make things so much more consistent... But I am probably missing the complete picture...

Comment: `void` is a type in C++, just not a data-type (i.e. you can have `void` functions, but not `void` data objects). Instead, if you find it necessary, you can try to use `void*` (casting an existing data-type) for data

Comment: You don't need to specialize for `void`. It's perfectly OK to `return` a function call whose return type is `void`.

Comment: Wow - how could I miss that 'return void' thing?  Seems I learned something wrong some time in the past, and it stuck!  Big thanks for the many useful answers, extremely helpful! :-)

Comment: Thanks again - code looks much cleaner now, everything works nicely, and I learned a number of things from your answers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

```
template <typename IMPL, typename RET>
RET call (functor <IMPL> func, 
          IMPL * impl)
{ 
  return func.call (impl);
}
```

should really be

```
template <typename RET, typename IMPL>
RET call (functor <IMPL> func, 
          IMPL * impl)
{ 
  return func.call (impl);
}
```

(I inversed `RET` and `IMPL` in the template argument list) so that you can call the function like

```
call<int>(f, impl);
```

instead of having to type

```
call<impl_type, int>(f, impl);
```

Indeed, the compiler cannot deduce `RET`, so you have to provide it yourself.

Second, you don't need to overload for `void`, since it is OK to return a `void` expression. If you want, you can add an overload:

```
template <typename IMPL>
void call(functor<IMPL> func, IMPL* impl)
```

and use `call(f, impl)` when calling this overload.

If you have access to C++0x, consider using `decltype`.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that, firstly, if you have a function that returns void, then it's perfectly legitimate to `return` a void expression- such as the call of another function that returns void, and secondly, `void` *is* a full type in C++ and you can pass it to templates as much as you like.

Answer (score 2):

If your `functor` template class already has a typedef for RET, you can do this instead:

```
template <typename IMPL>
typename functor<IMPL>::RET call (functor <IMPL> func, 
          IMPL * impl)
{ 
  return func.call (impl);
}
```

and not bother with the overload. Also, what is the compiler you are using? All standard-conformant compilers allow you to return the result of a `void` function from a `void` function.

Comment: "*VC++ 2010 allows you to return the result of a void function from a void function.*" All standard-conformant compilers do.

Comment: @ildjarn, yes, well... updating with that phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution for partial specialization of functions involves using a helper class template with the same template arguments, with a single method with the same arguments as your function.  The template class can then be partially specialized.

In your case, however, I would think you should be able to use `void` as your return type, as noted by the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using function overloading:

```
template <typename IMPL, typename RET>
RET call (functor <IMPL> func, 
          IMPL * impl)
{ 
  return func.call (impl);
}

template <typename IMPL>
void call (functor <void_t> func, void_t * impl) 
{ 
  func.call (impl);
}
```

Also, `void` is a type in C++; what makes you think that it isn't?

Comment: This probably misses though, what the template parameter for functor stands for (apparently the type of the pointer passed to the `call` method).